# Debugging child process not working with set detach-on-fork off

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, fork

I have the below simple program.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHILD 0

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    printf(" My pid = %d \n", getpid());
    getchar();
    pid = fork();
    if( pid == CHILD){
        printf(" child: My pid = %d \n", getpid());
        while(1);
    }
    else{
        printf(" My pid = %d \n", getpid());
        printf(" Newly created child pid = %d \n", pid);
        while(1);
    }
}
```

I am trying to debug it with gdb. I want to debug both parent and child process.  I used the following commands

```
Reading symbols from ./1...done.
(gdb) b 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x73f: file 1.c, line 12.
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off
(gdb) r
Starting program: ./1 
 My pid = 121710 


Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.c:12
12      pid = fork();
(gdb) n
[New process 121715]
Reading symbols from ./1...done.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x73f

(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 1    process 121710    ./1 
  2    process 121715    ./1 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ac8b1c in __libc_fork () at ../sysdeps/nptl/fork.c:135
#1  0x0000555555554744 in main () at 1.c:12
(gdb) n
[New process 121715]
Reading symbols from ./1...done.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x73f
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x73f
```

Can you guys please help me about the mistake I am making in the above gdb commands.

Comment: *"I want to debug both parent and child process"* - I don't think you can do both, but I could be wrong. I think you need to pick either the parent or the child. You may also need `set follow-fork-mode parent` or `set follow-fork-mode child`. Also see [4.11 Debugging Forks](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) in the GDB manual.

Comment: I was not referring to debug both at the same time. I want to stop one of the process and then move between them using inferior command

Comment: Judging from the addresses, you are likely using Linux/x86_64. I could not reproduce the behavior you observed using either gdb-8.2 or 8.3.

Comment: Did you run the above code in gdb and as well as the same commands

Answer (score 0):

I got the same  problem  when I used gdb 8.1 to debug fork(), with the same debug option.

One solution is to delete all breakpoints before calling fork(). For example, when you create a breakpoint in the previous source line of fork() for stepping to fork()，you should delete all breakpoints after current inferior stopped at this breakpoint, and then current inferior  can  continue to run successfully without a error prompt like `cannot insert breakpoint……`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a discussion form. If you are going to post an answer please make sure it is an answer. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get a better understand of what an answer is. Please also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)